# Erlang: Is there a way to "inherit" in a -spec?

Tags: erlang, specifications

Is there a way to "inherit" specifications in a -spec in Erlang?

Let me give an example:

I'm writing a typical convenience function like:

```
start_link(Opts) -> gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [Opts], []).
```

I want to write the -spec like:

```
-spec start_link(Opts) -> Result when
    Opts :: [Opt],
    Opts :: {timeout, pos_integer()}
          | {return_type, ReturnType},
    ReturnType :: binary | string,
```

The result of gen_server:start_link/3 is

```
Result = {ok,Pid} | ignore | {error,Error}
Pid = pid()
Error = {already_started,Pid} | term()
```

I have to copy this or use a template for start_link functions.
What I would like to do is to inherit the result of gen_server:start_link/3 somehow.

Is there any way to do this?
Any thoughts on this?

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write a type definition like:

```
-type start_link_ret() :: {ok,pid()} | ignore | {error,{already_started,pid()} | term()}
```

(You can't use `when` in `-type` definitions, so it all needs to go into the same expression.)

And then write your spec like:

```
-spec start_link(Opts) -> start_link_ret() when
    Opts :: [Opt],
    Opts :: {timeout, pos_integer()}
          | {return_type, ReturnType},
    ReturnType :: binary | string.
```

If you're going to use `start_link_ret()` in several modules, you can export it:

```
-export_type([start_link_ret/0]).
```

and then use it as `foo:start_link_ret()` in other modules.

Comment: It seems that it's as good as it gets. I was trying to provide a set of "type modules", which could be included as dependency to a project, so I didn't have to copy them into each project. Like gen_server_types:start_link_ret(). But if these external types don't get included into the docs properly (the cause might be me). When clicking on the link in the edoc-generated html the link leads to nirvana. I will include the type modules via my project templates then. Thank you!